# Does it make sense to have both name and a pointer to a structure?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, coverity

```
typedef struct net_path_s
{
    uint8    path_len;                     /* network path length */
    uint8    net_path[2 * MAX_ROUTE_LEN];  /* network path */
} net_path_t, *net_path_pt;
```

The pointer is meant for the structure.
Does it make sense to have both name and a pointer? And why are they using it?

Comment: If you read a bit on SO you will notice that having a typedef for a pointer is frequently called bad practice as it hides the nature of the pointer behind a type name. As a result especially beginners get confused about the number of `*` that is needed to pass the correct parameter or to return a pointer from a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are 2 things (or perhaps even 3) done at once. They can be decomposed into first:

```
struct net_path_s
{
    uint8    path_len;                     /* network path length */
    uint8    net_path[2 * MAX_ROUTE_LEN];  /* network path */
};
```

that defines a `struct`.

And second:

```
typedef net_path_s net_path_t, *net_path_pt;
```

that creates two `typedef`s. One is `net_path_t` which is an alias of `net_path_s` and the other is `net_path_pt` which is an alias of `net_path_s*`.

The latter is conceptually "creation of pointer type".

C syntax is "a pointer to type X". There is `char` and `char*` is a pointer to it. `char*` looks like a mere variant of `char`, as in `char a, *b, c;`.

Humans usually find it easier to think in "a type of pointer to X" way. So that's the rationale for typedef `char*` as eg. `pstr`. Now `pstr` looks like a type of its own. So you write `char a, c; pstr b;`.

Answer (score 2):

Because this declaration is a `typedef` it defines types, not variables. `net_path_t` is another name for this structure type, and `net_path_pt` is another name for a pointer to this structure type. You don't need to have both.

For some reason, some people prefer to write `net_path_pt` instead of `net_path_t*`. Defining pointer typedefs seems to be common in older APIs.